Plotting the polygon
There is a model that checks the entry of a point into an arbitrary polygon. Simulation graphs can show time-dependent variables. Is it possible to somehow plot the polygon itself and the point on it on the graph during modeling?

Not during modeling but during simulation. You can use DynamicSelect but I am unsure if it will work for your case as we would need to support different arrays of records, something like: annotation(DynamicSelect(static_diagram_polygon, if pointInside then {Polygon, Point} else {Polygon}).
